# How do I completely unpublish a node (not just change revision state) when using Workbench Moderation with rules?

Tags: 7, nodes, workbench, rules

I am attempting to use [rules scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to automatically 'archive' content after a set period. Essentially, I want the content to disappear for everyone except administrators. Ordinarily, I would just use the standard 'unpublish node' action, but I have installed [workbench moderation](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) and this does not unpublish the node. If I attempt to simply change the revision state to Draft, the state changes but the node is not unpublished. Is there any way I can unpublish the node programatically? Should I look at some kind of access control module instead?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suppose it's a bit late, but this issue is discussed in and should be mostly solved by https://drupal.org/node/1436260 once the issue is fixed. You should be able to unpublish the node, and as long as the code calls node_save, workbench moderation should set the state back to draft. If you want a different state, e.g. "archived", you'll probably have to come up with something custom.